# Checkstyle: enforce whitespace on inside of array literals

Tags: java, checkstyle

I was wondering if there were any rules to make this a violation: `private static final long[] ARRAY = {1L};` as I would rather have it like this: `... = { 1L };`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's [WhitespaceAround](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_whitespace.html#WhitespaceAround) which accepts [ARRAY_INIT](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/TokenTypes.html#ARRAY_INIT) token as configuration parameter:

Example:

```
<module name="WhitespaceAround">
  <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_INIT"/>
</module>
```

---

Edit: it looks like this is currently not possible (with default checkstyle). The WhitespaceAround ARRAY_INIT only checks for outer whitespace, not inner whitespace. NoWhitespaceAfter allows to specify ARRAY_INIT, but `WhitespaceAfter` does not :(

I found the following github issue https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/issues/472 which contains a comment with a possible custom check implementation to assert whitespace inside of array literals. The last update to the ticket was in 2016 and I was unable to find the implementation is the sevntu.checkstyle project, but that might be a starting point for you. Perhaps you can bundle the implementation in a separate jar and include it as custom check in your checkstyle config.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried this and it didn't show any violations.

Comment: @DanielGoers I researched a bit more and it looks like this is not possible out of the box. I found a github issue however which provides a possible solution. See my updated answer.